# shellcode in x86_64 avoiding null byte in large constants like an absolute address?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, shellcode

I'm new to learning x86_64 assembly, trying to move something in address 0x400da6 to register eax, I use

```
mov    0x400da6, %eax
```

but that will causing a 00 at the end of the binary, how to avoid this?

```
 0:   8b 3c 25 a6 0d 40 00    mov    0x400da6,%eax
```

Comment: Many ways. You could for example load `0x400da6+0x11111111` and then subtract that. You could load `0x400da6XX` and then right shift.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need a tmp register (for example EAX which you're about to overwrite anyway) to construct the address in a way that avoids any 00 bytes, then `mov (%rax), %eax`.  There's no encoding for a load that uses a 24-bit absolute address.

For example:

```
mov $0x400da6 + 0x1111111, %eax
mov -0x1111111(%rax), %eax
```

The resulting machine code is:

```
                note non-zero high byte
                    vv
   0:   b8 b7 1e 51 01          mov    eax,0x1511eb7
   5:   8b 80 ef ee ee fe       mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rax-0x1111111]
```

You can use any constant you want, as long as it fits in a 32-bit sign-extended disp32 so you can use it as part of the addressing mode.  If you want other operations like XOR, you'll need to XOR separately from the load; x86 addressing modes can only add 2's complement sign-extended 8 or 32-bit values.